# Delete HTML Elemented from iFramed site

Tags: javascript, iframe, iframe-resizer

I would like to iframe a specific portion of https://aliciabryantmayes.myhomehq.biz/newsletters page. To show only the screenshot portion.

[image]

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to do this from JavaScript, in your site at "http://example.com" (e.g. a different domain) that is wrapping this site in an `<iframe>` then the answer is **NO**, you can't. It is a security permission issue, you can't modify content on another domain.

If you are wrapping this page in another page from the same domain (e.g. you own this site)... then you can.

*It gets a bit more complicated if we are talking about browser extensions*

Alternatively, if you want to show only a portion of the content from another site on your site, you have some options.

**Option 1**: Use their API (if they provide one) to get the data, parse and present it as needed.

**Option 2**: Make a serverside request to "HTML screen scrape" content from a 3rd party site. Be careful not to overdo this (fetching a copy and caching it would be better than fetching it every time you load your page)... and beware that the 3rd party may still complain/throttle or block you.

Answer (score 0):

A bit of CSS should do the trick :)

```css
#my-div
{
    width    : 400px;
    height   : 200px;
    overflow : hidden;
    position : relative;
}

#my-iframe
{
    position : absolute;
    top      : -100px;
    left     : -100px;
    width    : 1280px;
    height   : 1200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="my-div">
<iframe src="http://www.example.com" id="my-iframe" scrolling="no"></iframe>
</div>
```

You can fiddle with it as needed.

Edit: My codepen example: https://codepen.io/Benjamin-Dover/pen/zYojKbz